# whats wrong with this syntax??

Tags: jquery, ajax, ready

i want to define this script, cause i want to call it:

```
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    //Show and hide the Loading icon on Ajax start/end

    $j('.bwbps_uploadform').submit(function() { 
        $j('#bwbps_message').html('');
        bwbpsAjaxLoadImage(this);
        return false; 

    });
```

and now:

```
var myFunction;
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    //Show and hide the Loading icon on Ajax start/end
myFunction = function() {
    $j('.bwbps_uploadform').submit(function() { 
        $j('#bwbps_message').html('');
        bwbpsAjaxLoadImage(this);
        return false; 

    });
});
```

can anybody help me to fix this script??

Comment: are you sure that your `$j` is actually jQuery?

Comment: $j sounds weird. Did you declare is like that, or is it a typo? i usually use $(document) as a declaration.

Comment: Why do you want to assign `myFunction` inside your document ready handler but declare the actual `myFunction` var outside? In a general sense it will "work" (you would later call it with `myFunction()`), but I don't see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: j: var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing your document ready function properly:

```
var myFunction;
$j(document).ready(function () {
    //Show and hide the Loading icon on Ajax start/end
    myFunction = function () {
        $j('.bwbps_uploadform').submit(function () {
            $j('#bwbps_message').html('');
            bwbpsAjaxLoadImage(this);
            return false;

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hi and thank you. firebug: "SyntaxError: syntax error
error source line:
 } "

Comment: Your welcome. You can now accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @FrediKarschuk sorry i can not help you as you didn't provide us with the `$j` function and therefor Im not getting any other mistake than the non defined function.

Comment: @FrediKarschuk ok, now here you have the fiddle. See there's no errors  in the console: http://jsfiddle.net/mLbuu/1/

Comment: var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: @FrediKarschuk I consider you should open a new question for that... and give us more code. I can not help you more with your syntax because as far as i know it is good.

Comment: ok, can't add a new question here.... must wait 7 hours.. will add a new new question xD